# Dynamic X-axis Excel Graph Displaying Military Time

Tags: excel, graph

I am not certain this is possible but I am trying to display my data in for form of a graph with 2 lines.  X-axis is time in Military Format, Y-axis is the count of items in that time.

Standard graph runs from 0 > 23.  I am needing the X-axis to be dynamic based on a different start time in the day instead of 0 based on the specific items start time.

Example:
Item 1 has a start time of 05:00 and all counts of that item run from 05:00 that day until 05:00 the next day.

Item 2 has a start time of 14:00, with the same logics as Item 1.

I have 3 cells that control the table of date displayed in the graph: a date, a specific identifier for the item, and the start time for that item.

Here is an image of my graph; the red line indicates where the time should start and 0-3 should wrap around to the other end.  I would like the x-axis to be dynamic like this for every item as the start times are different.
[image]